# How can I make my frame smaller when I call CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: swift

I have two images: ball and obstacle. If the ball hits the obstacle it's game over.

But since my obstacle and ball are not shaped as a rectangle, it looks like it's gameover before they hit each other. I understand that their frame actually does hit each other. But in the game, my gameover function is called before it looks like my ball and obstacle intersect.

Hope to find some help so I can have the result that my two images really looks like they hit each other before my gameover function is called.

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, obstacle.frame) {
    gameOver()
}
```

Comment: you can inset the rect to make it smaller. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454218-cgrectinset

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I can't get it to work. Maybe I'm implementing it wrong? before my if statement, I declare my new rect:

CGRectInset(obstacle.frame, 2000, 2000).

@JoshHomann is this not correct?

Comment: Thats correct, but 2000,2000 seems very large and very arbitrary.  For instance with a ball instead of using the rect that contains a the circle, I would use the rect that is small enough to be contained by the circle.  Simple trig tells you that the height and width should be sqrt(2)/2 or  0.707 times the outer rect (sin(45)*radius*2) so let collisionFrame = CGRectInset(ball.frame, (1-0.707)*ball.frame.size.width, (1-0.707)*ball.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to p: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt((p.x - self.x) * (p.x - self.x) + (p.y - self.y) * (p.y - self.y)) 
    }
}



extension UIView {

    func collided(with otherView: UIView) -> Bool {
        let myRadius = bounds.width/2
        let hisRadius = otherView.bounds.width/2

        return self.center.distance(to: otherView.center) <= myRadius + hisRadius 
    }
}
```

Now it reads nicely too:

```
 if ball.collided(with: obstacle) {
     gameOver()
 }
```